# How to display multiple ListViews in one activity

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

In my application I need to display multiple (three) listviews at a time sections wise. Can anyone suggest me a best way to implement this.

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to look into fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Try to provide a more detailed answer. For someone who may know very little about Android and can't grasp ListViews yet, the official dev website on a concept much more complex than a ListView may be too far off.

Answer (score 0):

if you create the ListView's in an XML file, you can just specify the ID attribute like so: `android:id="@+id/listView1`, providing a different ID for each `ListView`. In your Java code, you will want to extend Activity and create three `ListView` objects and point them towards the IDs in your XML file. Once you have a handle on the ListView's, you want to create a data source and `ArrayAdapter<String>` for each `ListView`. I prefer to use `ArrayList<String>` over the convential `String[]` simple because, to me, they are easier to use. A working Java sample below would work for a single `ListView`. Duplicate the variables and objects twice more with differing names for the two other `ListViews`. Hope this helps:

```
public class MainListActivityExample extends Activity {

    ListView listView1;
    ArrayList<String> lvContents1 = new ArrayList<String>;
    ArrayAdapter<String> lvAdapter1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Tell the method which layout file to look at
        setContentView(R.layout.listViewExample_activity);

        // Point the ListView object to the XML item
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Create the Adapter with the contents of the ArrayList<String>
        lvAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lvContents1);

        // Attach the Adapter to the ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(lvAdapter1);

        // Add a couple of items to the contents
        lvContents1.add("Foo");
        lvContents1.add("Bar");

        // Tell the adapter that the contents have changed
        lvAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In order to add the other two ListViews, create two more `ListView` objects, two more `ArrayList<String>` objects, and two more `ArrayAdapter<String>` objects, each with corresponding names so you know which belongs to which. You can then follow the exact same steps to initialize them.